# Separation of variables with Poisson's equation in 2D

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I would like to find a solution to Poisson's equation (in 2D), using the separation of variables. The problem is the following (assuming that $x$ and $y$ are reals)

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=f(x,y)$ in the rectangle $\Omega=\{0<x<a, 0<y<b\}$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}}=0$ on $\partial \Omega$

$f(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{ll}
       {-}K & : c<x<d, e<y<f\\
       0 & : elsewhere
     \end{array}
   \right.$

where $0<c<d<a$ and $0<e<f<b$.

I am able to solve this problem (with the separation of variables) if one side of the rectangle $\Omega$ is a Dirichlet boundary condition ($u=0$), but not if all 4 sides are Neumann.

In that case (if 3 sides are Neumann and 1 is Dirichlet), the solution is of the form

$u=\sum_{h=1}^{\infty}(k_1 \cos mx + k_2 \sin mx)(k_3 \cosh my + k_4 \sinh my) + k_5 x + k_6 y + k_7$

with $m=\frac{h 2\pi}{2a}$ and the source term is expressed as a Fourier series $K(x)=\sum_{h=1}^\infty K_m \cos mx$.

Perhaps this is where I am wrong when solving this problem with 4 Neumann boundary conditions. I use the same general solution for $u$ (for the complimentary function) and the same particular integral (found using the Fourier expansion for $K$), but try to calculate the new coefficients $k_j$ for the new boundary conditions. Is this how I should proceed? Or would the general solution and Fourier expansion be different for that case?

Answer (score 2):

The pure Neumann problem (when you have the Neumann boundary condition on all parts of the boundary) has two features that distinguish it from the Dirichlet or mixed problems:

- Uniqueness does not hold, because if $u$ is a solution, so is $u+c$ for any constant $c$.
- Existence requires the compatibility condition $\int_\Omega f=0$.

To see where $\int_\Omega f=0$ comes from, recall that the Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient field $\nabla u$. By the divergence (Gauss) theorem, $\int_\Omega \Delta u$ is the flux of $\nabla u$ across $\partial \Omega$: 
$$\int_\Omega \Delta u = \int_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf n}\tag1$$
(using the outward normal vector). The Neumann condition requires the right-hand side of (1) to be zero.

In your situation, $\int_\Omega f=-K(d-c)(f-e)\ne 0$, hence there is no solution.

Comment: Do you mean there is no solution in general to this problem, or that the separation of variables cannot be used? Because there is a well-known solution to this problem using double Fourier series and I also converge to this result using the finite element method for this pure Neumann problem. I was just wondering if the separation of variables would also give the same result.

Comment: The well-known solution I am talking about using double Fourier is $u=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty A_{i,k} \cos m_i x \cos n_k y$, where $m_i a$ is an even multiple of $\pi/2$ and $n_k b$ is also an even multiple of $\pi/2$.